# python separating element in a list

Tags: python

i have a list that consists of just one element, that looks like this:

```
[<div class="closeColor">0</div>, <div class="closeColor">0</div>, <div class="openColor">6</div>]
```

and i would like to have a list of this kind (in this case 3 different elements of the list:

```
["<div class="closeColor">0</div>", "<div class="closeColor">0</div>", "<div class="openColor">6</div>"]
```

Further more:
Can someone helping me to find a way to have in the list just the numbers? `["0","0","6"]`

Thanks 
Federico

Comment: 1) The input is not valid Python. 2) The quotation marks in your target format don't work. You must escape them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) function.

```
>>> lst = ['<div class="closeColor">0</div>', '<div class="closeColor">0</div>', '<div class="openColor">6</div>']
>>> [re.search(r'(?<=>)[^<>]*(?=<)', i).group() for i in lst]
['0', '0', '6']
```

**Regular Expression:**

```
(?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
  >                        '>'
)                        end of look-behind
[^<>]*                   any character except: '<', '>' (0 or more
                         times)
(?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
  <                        '<'
)                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: Please stop trying to parse HTML with regexes. Use lxml or Beautifulsoup.

Comment: @MaxNoel op clearly mentions the list contents. I don't know what's wrong in the above.